How to Parse and Split FIX Messages into Columns in Tibco Spotfire?
I'm working with a table in Tibco Spotfire that contains FIX (Financial Information eXchange) messages stored as strings in a single column.
I need to split this column into multiple new columns, where each column represents a FIX tag and its corresponding value.
The format of the FIX messages is as follows:
tag number + "=" + value + special character ""
Does anyone have any tips or solutions for achieving this in Spotfire?
Thank you!
Example FIX message:
8=FIX.4.49=5935=034=51349=TEST52=20240920-14:46:02.37456=TEST10=181

Print with the special character SOH, that isn't printable:



can you show what that example FIX message would become? I there are 8 equal signs and I cannot tell what is the value and what is the special character

Special character is usually SOH, start of heading. It is a non-printable character.

I put a picture showing the special character that separates the tag and value pairs.

This question has nothing to do with the FIX-protocol tag. No answer will involve FIX at all. Might be any old string that has a similar format, your answers will be the same.

do the lines always have the same tags, and do you know how many there are in advance? Is the dataset big? Can you use data functions or Iron Python?

You can split the data into columns by manually creating calculated columns if your data has a consistent format and tags present in the FIX data. Manual is not ideal, but at least you would only have to do it one time.
For example, a calculated column with name '8' could be:
Split(Split([fix_column],'\u0001',1),'=',2)

The string '\u0001' is used to split the text on the SOH special character.
That will work as long as tag 8 in in the first position.
If you have a variable number of tags or tag position, then a more general solution would be to use a python data function. Pass in the fix column as parameter and put the result in a new table
import pandas as pd
r = []

for i, row in fix_col.items():
    tags = row.split('\u0001')
    tags = [tag for tag in tags if '=' in tag]
    for tag_value in tags:
        tag, value = tag_value.split('=')
        r.append([i, tag, value])
df_out = pd.DataFrame(r,columns=['row_index', 'tag_number', 'tag_value']).pivot(index='row_index',columns='tag_number',values='tag_value').reset_index()

That should give you a table like this

If this is a one-time thing you might also want to check out the Spotfire text to columns tool
